# TikZ - inscribe a rectangle into a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Say we have a given isosceles triangle (for example sides of lengths 8,12,12) and a given segment length `a`, smaller than the triangle's base (e.g. `a=6`).

How can I draw such a rectangle inscribed into the triangle that has two sides of length `a` (without manually calculating the other side's length) using TikZ/PGFPlots?

/EDIT: As promised, my try. The values are different for the sake of simplicity.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (3,0) -- (0,8) -- (-3,0) -- cycle;
    \draw (2,0) -- (2,y) -- (-2,y); % where y is calculated manually, e.g. from the similar triangles properties
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Awful solution, isn't it? :)

Comment: I think you should at least show a minimal working example (aka MWE) and some effort.

Comment: I'll do, tomorrow

Comment: This isn't homework, is it?

Comment: @marmistrz Let us see your try!

Comment: I will, surely, but I'm short on free time lately. When I find a while, sure.

Comment: @marmistrz The example you provided is ‘‘minimal’’ enough, but not ‘‘working’’, meaning that it lacks the `\documentclass{}`, `\usepackage{}`, `\begin{document}`, etc, instructions which are necessary for it to be executed straight out of the box :-)

Comment: @fpast: I'll remember it for the future questions.

Comment: @cfr: No, we don't use LaTeX in our school at all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TikZ solution

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (-4,0)coordinate(a)--(4,0)coordinate(b);
\path[name path=C1] (8,0) arc (0:90:12);
\path[name path=C2] (-8,0) arc (180:90:12);
\path[name intersections={of=C1 and C2,by=s}]  ;
\draw[name path=T0] (b)--(s) --(a);
\path[name path=T1] (-3,0) -- ++(0,10);
\path[name path=T2] (3,0) -- ++(0,10);
\path[name intersections={of=T0 and T1,by={b1}}]  ;

\path[name intersections={of=T0 and T2,by=b2}] ;

\draw (a-|b1) --(b1) --(b2) --(a-|b2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With MetaPost, without comments.

```
\documentclass[border = 2bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    u = cm; a = 6; b = 8; c = 12;

    z1 + z2 = origin; z2 - z1 = u*b*right;
    z3 = u*(c +-+ .5b)*up;
    draw z1 -- z2 -- z3 -- cycle;

    z4 - z1 = z2 - z5; z5 - z4 = u*a*right;
    z6 = whatever[z5, z5 + up] = whatever[z2, z3];
    z7 = whatever[z4, z4 + up] = whatever[z1, z3];
    draw z4 -- z5 -- z6 -- z7 -- cycle;

    label.top("$" & decimal a & "$", .5[z6, z7]);
    draw image(drawdblarrow z1 -- z2; label.bot("$" & decimal b & "$", origin)) 
        yshifted -2.5labeloffset;
    draw thelabel.top("$" & decimal c & "$", .5[z1, z3]) 
        rotatedaround (.5[z1, z3], angle(z3 - z1));
    draw thelabel.top("$" & decimal c & "$", .5[z2, z3]) 
        rotatedaround (.5[z2, z3], angle(z2 - z3));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\const{\fpeval{sqrt((2*\lengthLeg)^2-\lengthBase^2)}}
\newcommand*\Middle{\fpeval{\lengthBase/2}}
\newcommand*\height{\fpeval{\const/2}}
\newcommand*\pointXa{\fpeval{(\lengthBase-\widthRectangle)/2}}
\newcommand*\pointXb{\fpeval{(\lengthBase+\widthRectangle)/2}}
%\newcommand*\pointXb{\fpeval{\pointXa+\widthRectangle}}
\newcommand*\pointY{\fpeval{\height*(\lengthBase-\widthRectangle)/\lengthBase}}

%%% Parameters
% Assumption: 2*\lengthLeg > \lengthBase > \widthRectangle
\def\lengthLeg{12}
\def\lengthBase{8}
\def\widthRectangle{6}

\psset{unit = \fpeval{min(1,8/\lengthLeg)}, dimen = m}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.6)(\lengthBase,\height)
  \pspolygon(0,0)(\Middle,\height)(\lengthBase,0)
  \psframe(\pointXa,0)(\pointXb,\pointY)
  \uput[270](\Middle,0){$\lengthBase$}
  \uput[90](\Middle,\pointY){$\widthRectangle$}
 \psset{linestyle = none, offset = 9pt}
  \pcline(0,0)(\Middle,\height)
  \ncput{$\lengthLeg$}
%  \pcline(\Middle,\height)(\lengthBase,0)
%  \ncput{$\lengthLeg$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is choose the values of `\lengthLeg`, `\lengthBase`, and `\widthRectangle`; the drawing will then be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

An homothetic solution :

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\Base{8}
\def\Rect{6}

\coordinate (A) at (-\Base/2,0) ;
\coordinate (B) at (\Base/2,0) ;

\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (0,0) ;
\draw[name path=C1] (\Base,0) arc (0:90:12);
\draw[name path=C2] (-\Base,0) arc (180:90:12);
\path[name intersections={of=C1 and C2,by=C}]  ;
\end{scope}

\coordinate (A') at ($(C)!\Rect/\Base!(A)$) ;
\coordinate (B') at ($(C)!\Rect/\Base!(B)$) ;

\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle ;
\draw (A-|A')--(A')--(B')--(B-|B') ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```